# How to properly slice just the integers from a list?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to average the grades from the input below. How do I slice out the name and just pass the integers to my calcAvg function? The grades are of variable length so my guess is I need to somehow slice my collection from element 1 to the size of the list?

input: Jack:90,80,70,90,50 Jill:80,100,30 Mary:20,100,90,80

```
    fun main(){

    print("Enter your grades: ")

    val studentGrades = mutableListOf<String>()

    while (true){
        val input = readLine()!!
        if (input.isNullOrBlank()) break
        else
            studentGrades += input
    }

    for (i in studentGrades){
        val splitRecords = i.split(" ")
        for (j in splitRecords){
            val splitName = j.split(":", ",")//split the name from the grades
        }
    }
}

fun calcAvg(list: List<Double>): Double{
    return list.average()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, I think.

After splitting out individual records<sup>*</sup>, I'd split on just ":" to separate the name from the grades list.  That should give you a list of two items: the name, and the grades list, so you can treat those separately.  A naive way would be:

```
val nameAndGradesList = j.split(":")
val name = nameAndGrades[0]
val gradesList = nameAndGrades[1]
```

But there's a simpler way of doing that, using a [destructuring declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html):

```
val (name, gradesList) = j.split(":")
```

Then you can separate the grades list into individual grades, and convert them to numbers:

```
val grades = gradesList.split(",").map{ it.toDouble() }
```

I guess you can take it from there…

Note that all this code assumes every record is in the right format; if not, it's liable to do strange things (e.g. crash by throwing an exception, or — even worse — give wrong results).  In production code, you'd usually want to check for that, and handle invalid records in an appropriate and predictable way.

---

<sup>(* You wouldn't need the first split if each record were on a separate line, which is the usual way.)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for offering the solution using destructuring. It worked for me. Very much appreciate the help.